# How to call a function on a div with a particular id

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a function called

```
function add_slider_here(){
}
```

which when called creates a progress bar.

Now I want to call the function with respect to a id of the div and attach the progress bar to it.

I see the way of doing it would be to append the created progress bar to the div which I already have. What is the best way to achieve something like this:

I have two divs with ids say `id1`  and `id2`

```
<div id="id1"></div> 
content here

<div id="id2"></div>
```

Now what I want is that when I call a function like :

```
$("#id1").add_slider_here();
```

It should actually add the slider in that div only.
how to create a function like that.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a jQuery plugin as follows:

```
$.fn.add_slider_here = function(){
    var ele = this; // ele will be jQuery object for your id
    // rest of your code to add progress bar from add_slider_here function in this element
}
```

Now you can call it like

```
$('#id1').add_slider_here();
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
(function ( $ ) {
    $.fn.add_slider_here = function() {
        //code here
    };

}( jQuery ));
```

Now you can use like this

`$(selector).add_slider_here();`

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $.fn.add_slider_here = function(){
            $(this).html("<span>slider html</span>");
        }
        $(function(){
            $('#id1').add_slider_here();
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="id1"></div>
        <div id="id2"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```